# Reproject raster from rectilinear LCC to rectilinear GK

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, grids-graticules, pyproj, rectangle

I have many climate raster (netcdf) in a rectilinear grid in LCC projection (EPSG 3034) and I want to reproject it with python to a local Gauß Kryger projection (31467).
Reprojecting every raster middle point with pyproj works great, but in the new system it's of course not rectilinear anymore and I would like to change that.
The lower left corner should remain in the original position but in the new raster, the cells should be also a rectilinear grid with reference to the new GK system (with neighbouring cells only having a different x **or** y coordinate). Is that reprojection with little shift and interpolation somehow easily doable in python? I'm sorry if my question is not fully clear.

Comment: Are you familiar with rioxarray: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject.html?

Comment: reproject_match could work for me, I will take a closer look. Thank you!